# Replace duplicate value in a an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
let lettersOfTheWord =["W",'H','A','T','E','V','E','R'];
let guessedLetters = lettersOfTheWord.map(()=>'_');
var count=0;
function guessLetter(letter){
    for(let i=0; i<lettersOfTheWord.length;i++){
        if (letter===lettersOfTheWord[i] && guessedLetters[i]==='_'){
            guessedLetters[i]=letter;
            console.log("You entered:" + letter);
            console.log(`The current guessed letters: ${guessedLetters.toString()}`);
            console.log("Congradulations! You found a new letter.");
            count++;
            console.log(count);
        }
        if (letter!==lettersOfTheWord[i] && guessedLetters[i]!=='_'){
            console.log("wrong letter");
        }
    }
    if (count===lettersOfTheWord.length){
        console.log("you win");
    }
}
   

guessLetter("W");
guessLetter("H");
guessLetter("A");
guessLetter("T");
guessLetter("E");
guessLetter("H");
guessLetter("E");
guessLetter("R");
```

So I have changed my code now.
The new problem is what if I would like to print out the "wrong letter" information if the call function has a wrong argument?

---

```
 let lettersOfTheWord =['F','O','X',"X"];
 let guessedLetters = [];
 let generateUnderScore = function(word){
    for (let i =0; i<word.length; i++){
        guessedLetters.push("_");
    }
    //console.log(guessedLetters.toString());
    return guessedLetters;
} //to generate underscore.
generateUnderScore(lettersOfTheWord);
 let guessLetter =function(letter){
     for (let i=0; i<lettersOfTheWord.length;i++){
         if (letter===lettersOfTheWord[i]){
             let index=lettersOfTheWord.indexOf(letter);
             guessedLetters[index]=letter;
             console.log(guessedLetters);
    
         }
     }
     console.log("You entered:" + letter);
     console.log(`The current guessed letters: ${guessedLetters.toString()}`);
     console.log("Congradulations! You found a new letter.")

     
    }
 

  guessLetter("F");
  guessLetter("O");
  guessLetter("X");
  guessLetter("X");
```

This is what my code looks like, for the last function call `guessLetter("X")`, I would like the output to be something like:

```
You entered:X
The current guessed letters: F,O,X,X
Congratulations! You found a new letter.
```

However, it ends up with:

```
You entered:X
The current guessed letters: F,O,X,_
Congratulations! You found a new letter.
```

I noticed the duplicate of letter "X" was not replaced, but how do I fix this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: Do not use an array. Use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I little bit of simplified your code.

```js
const UNKNOWN_LETTER = '_';
let lettersOfTheWord =['F','O','X',"X"];
let guessedLetters = lettersOfTheWord.map(() => UNKNOWN_LETTER);

function guessLetter(letter){
    lettersOfTheWord.forEach((_letter,i)=>{
        if (letter===_letter && guessedLetters[i] === UNKNOWN_LETTER) {
            guessedLetters[i]=letter;
            console.log(guessedLetters);
            console.log("You entered:" + letter);
            console.log(`The current guessed letters: ${guessedLetters.toString()}`);
            console.log("Congradulations! You found a new letter.")
        }
    });
}

guessLetter("F");
guessLetter("O");
guessLetter("X");
guessLetter("X");
```

The problem was in your `if` you should add `&& guessedLetters[i]==='_'` to your code.
And remove `let index=lettersOfTheWord.indexOf(letter);` then replace `i` instead of `index`

Also, you can use the `for ... in` loop. To use the break and skip unnecessary checks

```js
const UNKNOWN_LETTER = '_';
let lettersOfTheWord =['F','O','X',"X"];
let guessedLetters = lettersOfTheWord.map(() => UNKNOWN_LETTER);

function guessLetter(letter){
    for(const i in lettersOfTheWord){
        if (letter===lettersOfTheWord[i] && guessedLetters[i]===UNKNOWN_LETTER) {
            guessedLetters[i]=letter;
            console.log(guessedLetters);
            console.log("You entered:" + letter);
            console.log(`The current guessed letters: ${guessedLetters.toString()}`);
            console.log("Congradulations! You found a new letter.");
            break;
        }
    }
}

guessLetter("F");
guessLetter("O");
guessLetter("X");
guessLetter("X");
```

TIPS:

- you can remove function `generateUnderScore`
- learn more about ES6 map & forEach
- you don't need to provide function to your `let`. Just create `function name(..) {...}` I think, this is more clerable

Comment: what does this do ?  `()=>'_'`

Comment: the `map` function creates a new array with the same length like `lettersOfTheWord` but, sets for the each keys the "_" value , so you will receive a `["_", "_", "_", "_"]`

Comment: i have a new question regarding the code, could you please look into it for me?

Comment: what is that question?

Answer (score 0):

**Your Issue:**

When you try to find the index of `"X"` from `lettersOfTheWord`, it will always return `2` which is the fist occrance of `"X"` in `lettersOfTheWord`

**Fix to your problem.**

[`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) accepts `fromIndex` as an optional [parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#parameters). You can use the index of the execution as the `fromIndex`.

**Your Fixed Fiddle**

```js
let lettersOfTheWord = ['F', 'O', 'X', "X"];
let guessedLetters = [];
let executionIndex = 0;
let generateUnderScore = function (word) {
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    guessedLetters.push("_");
  }
  //console.log(guessedLetters.toString());
  return guessedLetters;
} //to generate underscore.
generateUnderScore(lettersOfTheWord);
let guessLetter = function (letter) {
  for (let i = 0; i < lettersOfTheWord.length; i++) {
    if (letter === lettersOfTheWord[i]) {
      let index = lettersOfTheWord.indexOf(letter, executionIndex);
      guessedLetters[index] = letter;
      // console.log(guessedLetters);
    }
  }
  console.log("You entered:" + letter);
  console.log(`The current guessed letters: ${guessedLetters.toString()}`);
  console.log("Congradulations! You found a new letter.");
  executionIndex++;
}
guessLetter("F");
guessLetter("O");
guessLetter("X");
guessLetter("X");
```

**Better Solution**

You can rewrite `guessedLetters` using `Array.map`. For loop isirrelavent, you can use `Array.indexOf` itself and can check whether the found index is greater that -1, which means element exist in array.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
let lettersOfTheWord = ['F', 'O', 'X', "X"];
let guessedLetters = lettersOfTheWord.map(item => '_');
let executionIndex = 0;

let guessLetter = function (letter) {
  const index = lettersOfTheWord.indexOf(letter, executionIndex);
  index > -1 ? guessedLetters[index] = letter : {};
  console.log("You entered:" + letter);
  console.log(`The current guessed letters: ${guessedLetters.toString()}`);
  console.log("Congradulations! You found a new letter.");
  executionIndex++;
}
guessLetter("F");
guessLetter("O");
guessLetter("X");
guessLetter("X");
```

Comment: there is a problem if you guess letters in that way -> `F, X, O, X`